# Word or phrase for a situation when your intention is to save something but end up in loss

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, vocabulary

I don't know what this situation is called when we end up in loss but intention was to save/protect.

Example:

1. I am trying to improve something but made it worse
2. I am trying to fix a thing and broken other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“*One step forward and two steps backward*” would often describe these circumstances.

Comment: Thanks Anton. Can you help me with related single-word and usage in sentence?

Comment: I am sorry that  could not think of a single word other than *endeavour* or *attempt* which, although part of appropriate phrases *vain endeavour* ( or *vain attempt*) (= an attempt that failed) do not alone quite have the sense of trying then failing.